# Git push.default simple not working

Tags: git, git-push

I set my `push.default` to simple and expected this to work without setting upstream explicitly. Do I have the wrong expectation or did I miss something?

```
$ git co develop
Switched to branch 'develop'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.

$ git pull
Already up-to-date.

$ git co -b 'push_test'
Switched to a new branch 'push_test'

$ git push
fatal: The current branch push_test has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin push_test


$ git config --list | grep push.default
push.default=simple

$ git config --list
credential.helper=osxkeychain
alias.co=checkout
alias.st=status
user.name=Drew Arrigoni
push.default=simple
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
remote.origin.url=git@github.com:Foo/foo.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.develop.remote=origin
branch.develop.merge=refs/heads/develop
user.email=andrewarrigoni@foo.com
```

Comment: You have the wrong expectation: `simple` is not quite so simple, for historical reasons. The *first* push of a new branch requires using `git push -u` (`-u` is the short version of `--set-upstream`, in `git push` but not in `git branch`). Once you've done that, `simple` *does* become simple.

Comment: Alrighty. Is there a way to automatically set the upstream on a newly created branch? Would I need to look into git hooks or something similar?

Comment: No: the fundamental problem is that the upstream for your new branch (e.g., `push_test`) *will be* `origin/push_test`, but `origin/push_test` is your Git's memory of origin's `push_test` branch. Which doesn't exist... yet. Once you successfully `git push`, *then* they have a `push_test`, so *now* your Git creates your `origin/push_test` to remember their `push_test`, so *now* you can set it as an upstream. But you don't know that the create will work until you try the create operation. (Maybe they will refuse to create `push_test` because someone else created one just three seconds earlier!)

Comment: There is one short-cut you can use: it's harmless to set the upstream of `push_test` to `origin/push_test` if the upstream of `push_test` is already `origin/push_test`. This means you can just use `-u` on *every* push. The drawback is that if you do that, and then you choose to push your branch `push_test` to `origin`'s branch `master`, that will re-set your upstream to `origin/master`.

Comment: Cool beans! So something like this: `git config --global alias.push push -u origin \`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD\`` would basically do what I want it to do, with the caveat that I would need to undo the alias if for any reason I wanted to push somewhere else. Thanks much Torek!

Comment: Well, you can't alias a built in command either: you'd need to use `p` or `pu` or some such. Also, note that you can just `git push -u <remote> HEAD`; Git will figure out what branch that is.

Comment: Figured that out about 30 seconds after I commented. I ended up with `git config --global alias.up "push -u origin HEAD"`

Thanks again for the help! Feel free to write this up as an answer and I'll flag it as accepted if you so desire.